# Find $w$ that minimizes $w^TCw$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I really need help with this question. Let $C$ be a positive definite $n\times n$ covariance matrix and let $e$ be the eigenvector associated with its smallest eigenvalue, scaled so that $e^Te = 1$. Let $k=1/(e^Tu)^2$ ($u$ is the unit vector). Assume no multiplicity of eigenvectors, i.e. if $e$ is the eigenvector associated with an eigenvalue then only multiples of $e$ are associated
with that eigenvalue. Find the set of all $n$-vectors $w$ that minimize $w^TCw$ subject to $w^Tw=k$. How many of
these minimization solutions satisfy the budget constraint? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What is the budget constraint?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. Budget constraint is $w^Tu=1$, where $u$ is the unit matrix.

Comment: I'm guessing we are to assume $e^\top u \neq 0$ too, given the definition of $k$. I would start by making a substitution $v = w / \sqrt{k}$, to write $\min_{w^\top w = k} w^\top C w$ in terms of $\min_{v^\top v = 1} v^\top C v$.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\x{\|x\|}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\B{\Big}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\B(#1\B)}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$For typing convenience, introduce the matrix inner product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
and rewrite $w$ in terms of the unconstrained vector $x$
$$\eqalign{
w &= k^{1/2}\,\frac{x}{\x} \qiq \big\|w\big\|^2_F = k \\
}$$
Write the objective function using the above notation, then calculate its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
\l &= C:ww^T \\
d\l
 &= C:\LR{w\,dw^T+dw\,w^T} \\
 &= \LR{C^T+C}:\LR{dw\,w^T} \\
 &= 2Cw:dw \\
 &= 2k^{1/2}Cw:d\fracLR{x}{\x} \\
 &= 2k^{1/2}Cw:\fracLR{\x\,dx-x\,d\x}{\x^2} \\
 &= 2k^{1/2}Cw:\fracLR{\x^2I-xx^T}{\x^3}dx \\
 &= 2k^{1/2}Cw:\fracLR{1}{k\x}\LR{kI-ww^T}dx \\
 &= \fracLR{2k^{1/2}}{k\x}\BR{kI-ww^T}\,Cw:dx \\
 &= \fracLR{2}{k^{1/2}\x}\BR{kCw-\l w}:dx \\
\grad{\l}{x}
 &= \fracLR{2}{k^{1/2}\x}\BR{kCw-\l w} \\
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero leads to an eigenvalue equation
$$\eqalign{
\LR{kC}w &=  \l w \\
}$$
which you've already solved (except for the scale factor of $k$). The eigenvalues will be reflect this scaling, but the *eigenvectors* will remain unchanged.